# Transfer Verilog Code to For Loops Syntax

Tags: fpga, verilog, synthesis

I have built an block that does simple moving average on a "factor" numbers in the vector.. and its works good for my needs.

My problem with it that I think my syntax is bit dumb.
I have an array and I push my data into the array and using the factor trigger (can be 2,4,8,16,32) I accumulate the data signals and than make right shift to divide by the factor value.

I read that using for loops is not recomendded but maybe its just nonsense and for loops in synthesis is perfectly fine.

someone can confirm that using for loop for my need is fine and how it can be done here so it be can be synthesized?

my code:

```
module average #
(
    --parameters--
)
(
    input                           clk,
    input                           rst_n,
    input  [FACTOR_WIDTH-1 : 0]     factor,  // Average (2, 4, 8, 16, 32)
    input  [INPUT_WIDTH-1  : 0]     din,

    --more inputs outputs--

);

    reg         [INPUT_WIDTH-1 :0]  din_dly [0:32-1];
    reg         [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0]  dout_sum;
    reg         [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0]  dout_shift;


    initial begin
        dout_sum    = {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        dout_shift  = {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};

        for (index = 0; index < 32; index = index + 1) begin
            din_dly[index]  = {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end
    end


    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin : average_logic
        if (~rst_n) begin
            dout_sum     <= {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            dout_shift   <= {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            --flags=0--
        end else begin
            if (--flags--) begin
                if (factor == 2) begin
                    dout_sum     <= din_dly[0] + din_dly[1];
                    dout_shift   <= dout_sum>>1;    //dout_sum / 2;
                end
                if (factor == 4) begin
                    dout_sum     <= din_dly[0] + din_dly[1] + din_dly[2] + din_dly[3];
                    dout_shift   <= dout_sum>>2;    //dout_sum / 4;
                end
                if (factor == 8) begin
                    dout_sum     <= din_dly[0] + din_dly[1] + din_dly[2] + din_dly[3]
                                 + din_dly[4] + din_dly[5] + din_dly[6] + din_dly[7];                      
                    dout_shift   <= dout_sum>>3;    //dout_sum / 8;
                end
                if (factor == 16) begin
                    dout_sum     <= din_dly[0] + din_dly[1] + din_dly[2] + din_dly[3]
                                 + din_dly[4] + din_dly[5] + din_dly[6] + din_dly[7]
                                 + din_dly[8] + din_dly[9] + din_dly[10] + din_dly[11]
                                 + din_dly[12] + din_dly[13] + din_dly[14] + din_dly[15];                      
                    dout_shift   <= dout_sum>>4;    //dout_sum / 16;
                end
                if (factor == 32) begin
                    dout_sum     <= din_dly[0] + din_dly[1] + din_dly[2] + din_dly[3]
                                 + din_dly[4] + din_dly[5] + din_dly[6] + din_dly[7]
                                 + din_dly[8] + din_dly[9] + din_dly[10] + din_dly[11]
                                 + din_dly[12] + din_dly[13] + din_dly[14] + din_dly[15]
                                 + din_dly[16] + din_dly[17] + din_dly[18] + din_dly[19]
                                 + din_dly[20] + din_dly[21] + din_dly[22] + din_dly[23]                       
                                 + din_dly[24] + din_dly[25] + din_dly[26] + din_dly[27]
                                 + din_dly[28] + din_dly[29] + din_dly[30] + din_dly[31];
                    dout_shift   <= dout_sum>>5;    //dout_sum / 32;
                end

                --logic--

            end else begin
                --logic--
            end
        end
    end

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if (~rst_n) begin
            din_dly[0]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[1]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[2]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[3]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[4]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[5]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[6]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[7]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[8]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[9]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[10] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[11] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[12] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[13] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[14] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[15] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[16] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[17] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[18] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[19] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[20] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[21] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[22] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[23] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[24] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[25] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[26] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[27] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[28] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[29] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[30] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            din_dly[31] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end else begin
            if (--flag--) begin
                if (factor == 2) begin
                    din_dly[0]  <= din;
                    din_dly[1]  <= din_dly[0];
                end
                if (factor == 4) begin
                    din_dly[0]  <= din;
                    din_dly[1]  <= din_dly[0];
                    din_dly[2]  <= din_dly[1];
                    din_dly[3]  <= din_dly[2];
                end
                if (factor == 8) begin
                    din_dly[0]  <= din;
                    din_dly[1]  <= din_dly[0];
                    din_dly[2]  <= din_dly[1];
                    din_dly[3]  <= din_dly[2];
                    din_dly[4]  <= din_dly[3];
                    din_dly[5]  <= din_dly[4];
                    din_dly[6]  <= din_dly[5];
                    din_dly[7]  <= din_dly[6];
                end
                if (factor == 16) begin
                    din_dly[0]  <= din;
                    din_dly[1]  <= din_dly[0];
                    din_dly[2]  <= din_dly[1];
                    din_dly[3]  <= din_dly[2];
                    din_dly[4]  <= din_dly[3];
                    din_dly[5]  <= din_dly[4];
                    din_dly[6]  <= din_dly[5];
                    din_dly[7]  <= din_dly[6];
                    din_dly[8]  <= din_dly[7];
                    din_dly[9]  <= din_dly[8];
                    din_dly[10] <= din_dly[9];
                    din_dly[11] <= din_dly[10];
                    din_dly[12] <= din_dly[11];
                    din_dly[13] <= din_dly[12];
                    din_dly[14] <= din_dly[13];
                    din_dly[15] <= din_dly[14];
                end
                if (factor == 32) begin
                    din_dly[0]  <= din;
                    din_dly[1]  <= din_dly[0];
                    din_dly[2]  <= din_dly[1];
                    din_dly[3]  <= din_dly[2];
                    din_dly[4]  <= din_dly[3];
                    din_dly[5]  <= din_dly[4];
                    din_dly[6]  <= din_dly[5];
                    din_dly[7]  <= din_dly[6];
                    din_dly[8]  <= din_dly[7];
                    din_dly[9]  <= din_dly[8];
                    din_dly[10] <= din_dly[9];
                    din_dly[11] <= din_dly[10];
                    din_dly[12] <= din_dly[11];
                    din_dly[13] <= din_dly[12];
                    din_dly[14] <= din_dly[13];
                    din_dly[15] <= din_dly[14];
                    din_dly[16] <= din_dly[15];
                    din_dly[17] <= din_dly[16];
                    din_dly[18] <= din_dly[17];
                    din_dly[19] <= din_dly[18];
                    din_dly[20] <= din_dly[19];
                    din_dly[21] <= din_dly[20];
                    din_dly[22] <= din_dly[21];
                    din_dly[23] <= din_dly[22];
                    din_dly[24] <= din_dly[23];
                    din_dly[25] <= din_dly[24];
                    din_dly[26] <= din_dly[25];
                    din_dly[27] <= din_dly[26];
                    din_dly[28] <= din_dly[27];
                    din_dly[29] <= din_dly[28];
                    din_dly[30] <= din_dly[29];
                    din_dly[31] <= din_dly[30];
                end
            end
            if (--some flags--) begin
                din_dly[0]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[1]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[2]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[3]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[4]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[5]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[6]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[7]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[8]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[9]  <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[10] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[11] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[12] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[13] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[14] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[15] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[16] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[17] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[18] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[19] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[20] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[21] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[22] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[23] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[24] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[25] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[26] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[27] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[28] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[29] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[30] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
                din_dly[31] <= {INPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            end
        end 
    end
endmodule
```

thanks!

Comment: For loops are perfectly fine for synthesis. Anybody who tells you different is absolutely wrong. My biggest issue with your code is that I would have added a 'valid' output signal to tel the next stage when the average values is correct.

Comment: @Oldfart thanks.. for loops is also fine with changing index? (factor) and inside the for loop accumulate object and so on?  about the output valid, yeah I know.. I hide all the not relevant logic for my question

Comment: For loops are fine for synthesis as long as the number of loops does not change - i.e. you cannot use a variable to control the loop limit, only constants and parameters.

Comment: @TomCarpenter ok so in another words I cant use in my code for loops? because the times Im going to run the for loop is controlled by the "factor" signal which controlled from outside the block, there is any solution for it?

Comment: You can however do something like `for (...i < 32 ...) ... dout_sum <= dout_sum  + ( (i > factor) ? 0 : din_dly[i])`. That way you still have the same number of loops always, but you simply add on (32-factor) zeros on in some of the loops. This will result in a chain of adders and multiplexers which may not give a high f-max.

Comment: You could also spit your calculations into multiple always blocks, one for each factor - use a grenerate for loop to create each different factor. Then use the factor variable to select which one is used. This will take up more space but could potentially run faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loops in Verilog can be used for synthesis purposes. However the caveat is that the number of loops must be known at synthesis because the tools will unroll the loop into hardware. This means your loop limit must be a constant, a `parameter/localparam`, or a `genvar`.

As such if you want to use for loops in your code, you'll need to find a way to factor it such that you have a constant number of loops. One such example might be:

```
reg [FACTOR_WIDTH-0:0] i;

always @ (posedge clk ... ) begin
    ...
    dout_sum = {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
         dout_sum = dout_sum + ( (i < factor) ? din_dly[i] : {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}} );
    end
    ...
end
```

That way you still have the same number of loops always, but you simply add on (32-factor) zeros on in some of the loops. This will result in a chain of adders and multiplexers which may not give a high f-max.

You would have to reconcile how to do `dout_shift`. This could be done with a simple lookup table to convert `factor` into how many bits to shift.

---

An alternate solution would be a `generate for` block which makes one set of logic for each different factor.

```
//logic to convert factor to a value 0-5 representing log2(factor). Can be a simple case statement.
reg [5:0] factorLog2;
...

reg [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0] dout_shift_all [5:0];
genvar i;
generate for (i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1) begin : factor_loop
    // Create the sum - this is the async part of the calculation
    reg [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0] dout_sum_factor;
    integer j;
    always @ * begin
        dout_sum_factor = {OUTPUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        for (j = 0; j < (1 << i); j = j + 1) begin
             dout_sum_factor = dout_sum_factor + din_dly[j];
        end
    end
    // Pipeline dout_sum_factor
    reg [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0] dout_sum_buf;
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        dout_sum_buf <= dout_sum_factor;
    end
    // Could make pipeline this but would take an extra clock cycle compared to original code
    always @ * begin 
       dout_shift_all[i] = dout_sum_buf >> i;
    end
end endgenerate

//Existing logic tweaked to use dout_shift_all
always @ (posedge clk ... ) begin
    ...
    dout_sum_shift = dout_shift_all[factorLog2]; 
    ...
end
```

This would produce more logic but would be faster as it's more parallel and pipelineable.

Comment: ok thanks! another question is that how important is to use for loops in this cases? does it looks bad to do it just in my way?

Comment: @MichaelAstahov "does it look bad" is subjective. If it works, it works. But what happens if you want to further parameterise your module - say in a later system you want to be able to average 64 times. Or in a smaller FPGA you might not have room for all factors so want to reduce it to max 16 times. It's easier to do that with loops.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, a bit longer answer:

For loops are perfectly fine for synthesis. Anybody who tells you different is absolutely wrong.

As Tom Carpenter says: the loop has to be deterministic. Which means this is not allowed:

```
for (i=0; i<factor; i=i+1) ...
```

But this is:

```
if (factor==2)
   for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1)
...
if (factor==4)
   for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
```

Note that there is a much better way to calculate a walking average over a series of numbers:

You add the numbers up but remember (e.g. in dual-ported memory or shift register) the data. Then you divide the sum by N. Now the next time a value arrives you add the new value to the sum, and subtract the oldest value.

The amount of storage is the same, but the amount of add/subtract logic is significant smaller

---

> and yea I saw this algorithm but I didn't know its make so much difference

It makes a huge difference. This one uses one adder and one subtractor plus a counter and comperator. Yours uses 1+3+8+15+31 = 58 adders.

Comment: ok thanks! another question is that how important is to use for loops in this cases? does it looks bad to do it just in my way?

Comment: and yea I saw this algorithm but I didnt know its make so much diffrence